# How is the concept of garbage collection related to non OOP languages

Tags: c++, c, garbage-collection, dynamic-memory-allocation

When using a language like `C++` without any automatic garbage collector I understand that you have to use destructors to clean up after your objects. But how is the notion of "cleaning up" related to non OOP languages. What is the standard way of cleaning up structs and built in types in `C` for example?

To make a concrete example, what would be the related notion of cleaning up when writing a long running `C` process?

Comment: In C you pretty much write functions not unlike destructors that do the cleanup using `free`.

Comment: In unmanaged languages, doesn't matter if they're "OO" or not, whatever you allocate you must free, it's as simple as that.

Comment: You're responsible for the clean-up. That doesn't necessarily mean you ahve to do so manually. Eg. you may choose to delegate the responsibility to C++'s `std::shared_ptr`, but you must choose some method. There is no default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) entry for Garbage collection

> In computer science, garbage collection (GC) is a form of *automatic memory management*.

and

> Garbage collection is often portrayed as the opposite of manual memory management, which requires the programmer to specify which objects to deallocate and return to the memory system.

In `C` language, there is no *automatic memory management* so we have to do *manual memory management*. Whatever memory is allocated (dynamically, at runtime) by a program (or programmer), the program (or programmer) needs to *release* the memory explicity, by using [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) function.

Failing to release the allocated memory will lead to [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 3):

In C, to deallocate dynamically allocated resources you must call `free`.

A common solution is to write functions that imitate destructors in that they do the cleanup for a specific struct by calling `free` where needed.

However it's worth noting that these cleanup function won't get called automatically as destructors do, and forgetting to call a cleanup function may result in memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Its not much different from using a garbage-collected language, When you write a class in a GC system, you must often write a finaliser or IDispose method too. This ensures that whatever resources you allocate in your class gets freed when the GC cleans up any objects based on that class. So a DB wrapper class might open a DB connection handle in its constructor, and you will write a finaliser to close that handle later.

Obviously - you've written code that opens the handle, and more code that closes it. This is the same principle for other languages, such as C. There is only 1 difference: if your class only manages memory, you can ignore both the creation and destruction of the memory used in the objects. In C, you have to both allocate and free memory that you use. In a GC language memory is handled for you.

You still have to manage non-memory resources however. When writing in a language such as C just think of memory as another resource.

Answer (score 1):

One could have a garbage-collection system in a non-GC language by using handles.  If one wanted to write a C program for an embedded system that had to handle a very large number of variable-length strings--many of them duplicates--in e.g. 64K of RAM, one could write an API for that whose members included the following:

```
// With 64K RAM, won't need over 64,000 string handles
typedef uint16_t st_handle;  
// Create new handle that initially identifies an empty string
st_handle st_create();
// Release handle
void st_release(st_handle st);
// Create a string object with a copy of the specified content and make
// the given handle identify it
void st_copy_content(st_handle st, const char *src, int src_length);
// Create a string object which holds a reference to a string held in memory
// that will never change (e.g. ROM), and make handle identify it
void st_make_reference(st_handle st, char *src, int src_length);
// Get length of string object associated with handle
int st_length(st_handle st);
// Copy portion of string object to character array or buffer
void st_get_range(st_handle st, int st_index, char *dest, int dest_length);
// Make one handle identify the same string as another
void st_assign(st_handle dest, st_handle src);
// Report how much memory is immediately available or could be made available,
// possibly performing a garbage-collection first based upon "mode" and
// "requirement".
int st_free_space(int mode, int requirement);
```

Before working a string-type variable, code would need to create a handle and store it in that variable; once done with the variable, code would need to release that handle.  Code may copy handles to other variables (e.g. for passing into functions), but each handle must be released after the last use, and neither used nor redundantly released after that.

Despite the need to manually create and release *handles*, working with much code could be much more efficient than working with manually-allocated *strings*.  Since each handle would identify a fixed-sized object (which would in turn identify a variable-length string), any "allocate-handle" request could be satisfied by returning the first available handle from the pool.  If strings are immutable, then allowing multiple handles to identify the same string would not only make string assignment (from one handle to another) faster than string copying--it would also eliminate the need to hold duplicate copies of string data in RAM.  Though not shown above, a suitable library could also include methods to concatenate, extract substrings, etc.

Code that needs to do things not provided by the library may need to copy data from them into suitably-sized buffers before working with them, and create new string objects from those buffers when done, but most programs won't be "working with" very many strings at a time--instead they'll work with one string in an array, then work with another, etc. so having a pool to manage the strings that aren't being "worked with" at any given time, and only take as much memory as the strings themselves require, can greatly improve efficiency.

Since the string pool would know there whereabouts of every reference to every string, it would be free to rearrange strings in memory.  Whereas a conventional string allocator would have trouble if code created many short strings, released half of them, and then tried to create a longer string, a handle-based allocator would have no difficulty.  It could if needed relocate to the top of the pool all strings to which references still exist, thereby making room for a larger string in the middle.  Further, an handle-pool allocator can be very thrifty.  While an ARM would normally use 4 bytes for each pointer to an allocated block of memory, and malloc would need an additional 4 bytes per object to track heap usage, a garbage-collected pool 64K or smaller would only require 2+2.  Single-character strings could be stored directly in a handle, while string objects of length 2-63 would only need one byte of overhead (longer strings may need more overhead depending upon length, but less than 2% in any case).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that object orientation is a *program design method*, for which a programming language may or may not have various convenient features built-in. How dynamic memory allocation is handled by a particular language isn't really related to OO, although it must be considered when writing the OO program.

Since C doesn't have the language features constructor/destructor, your object-oriented C program has to manually call an "init function" and a "destruct function". If you implement these properly by using the C language feature *incomplete type* (sometimes called "opaque type"), you achieve the very same thing as far as the OO design is concerned. But inconveniently, you have to do each call of these functions manually.

Just as it may be more inconvenient that you have to consider deletion when writing code in C++, compared to for example Java where you can just allocate away and let someone else (the garbage collector) clean up your mess, potentially at the expense of a slower program.